# why did my cat stare at me with her third eyelid pulled across?

Tags: cats

For the first time ever, she had her third eyelid, the one that pulls across from the inner corner, about a quarter of the way across both eyes in fact, but I have never seen her face like this, she was staring at me in a new way and not blinking love blinks when I  stroked her or closing her eyes and purring.

One factor might be that I have had to halt her from sitting on my computer keyboard as she altering the settngs in ways that needed a repair, she was getting stroked while sitting on the keyboard, which was hard to handle, so I out a book under the laptop so that she has no flat surface to sit on, one idea that I found on-line that might not be the best solution, after all. Though I sroke her when she  is on the armchair too.

Another factor is that I changed my coloured light-bulb for a white brighter one, an overhead light, nothing in her eyes, no brighter than the kitchen.

She has a suede rug on my desk, the run of my home 100% (bedroom and kitchen, living room, she goes where she wants, sleeps where she wants) food and water, clean litter, petting on offer, which is when she stared so, while on the suede rug, perhaps she is bored of it, but she usually bucks her head back to let me know that she wants me to stop, she scented me, rubbed her cheeks on my jacket. Still, she is not perky, she was like this in the kitchen too, just not herself...

I just want our special bond back. The bond with the love blinks. Maybe I am worrying over nothing and she will change back. Do cats have off days? Is she just growing up? She is four human years

Comment: This sounds like it could be an eye infection, eye irritation, or perhaps an illness. I would take her to the vet.

Answer (score 4):

If your cat is not her perky self (behavioral change) and is showing her third eyelid, she may be sick. Please take your cat to the vet.

Comment: Agreed. Either alone could be an indication of illness.